# copying information into repeating table component of infopath

Tags: infopath, infopath-2007

I am trying to modify an existing infopath form that contains repeating table container.User enters the details in the table and form is used by another program for processing.

The current requirement is for user should be able to copy data from somewhere and directly paste into table. The user may copy data containing multiple rows and paste it.This source could be anywhere and also the user can still enter data manually row by row so a data connection is not feasible.

But the data gets truncated with only first row getting entered in form as there is only one row present in the form. I found out this was the behavior after googling. Is there a work around for this. Like overwriting paste function using code?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does your code look like now?

Comment: @Brad currently i have a table component with  one row shown. So the user can paste one row and then click on Insert New Row and then paste again and so on. I want to create the required number of rows dynamically from the data being pasted.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot comment so I will have to leave this as an answer please do not down vote since I am trying to help you out.

Not sure this is possible but try to create a field that allows the user to enter a number of rows.  That way they could take a look at the number of rows in their excel spreadsheet and see that it's 32 (or whatever number).  Then you could take that number of rows and have the form create a repeating table with the number of rows specified.  That way they could paste in the number of rows they need to paste.

This would not be ideal of course but attempting something like this might be easier than overwriting a paste operation.

Comment: Thanks Nelson, this is how i implemented as i couldn't find way to overwrite in paste operation.